# How to exit a Mono-service?

Tags: c#, service, mono

I'm trying to exit my mono-service cleanly.

I'm building a mono-service, and to make things easy to debug, I am running it as:

```
mono-service --debug /etc/App.exe
```

This is great of course because the `Console.WriteLine("...")` I have in my code writes out to the screen.

The next thing I do is add the new thread in the OnStart, because of course then the code (service) would never be considered started.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Thread serviceThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartMyApplicationAsync));
    serviceThread.Start();
}
```

While with the `--debug` flag, the console writes work, but it does not exit, ever. I can only issue a `kill -9` to end the application. The service cannot even be restarted.

How can I exit my mono-service cleanly once I have started a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while, but I finally found: Console.IsOutputRedirected. (Part of .Net 4.5)

If anyone else find this post, the answer would be:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if(Console.IsOutputRedirected)
    {
        Thread serviceThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartMyApplicationAsync));
        serviceThread.Start();
    } else {
        StartMyApplicationAsync();
    }
}
```

This way when testing the applications with the `--debug` switch, it will respond/end to Ctrl+c